# How can I deserialize the OpaquePython function outputted from LazyDataframe.serialize?

Tags: python, rust, python-polars

I have a lazy dataframe that has a map with a UDF. When I call `ldf.serialize()` in python I get back a json outlining the various computations, including the map with the UDF. However, the UDF is serialized as some kind of array of numbers:

```py
def multiplyBy2(x):
  return x*2
```

```
[128, 5, 149, 198, 1, ..., 134, 82, 48, 46]
```

Looking at the polars source code, I found that the UDF is first serialized using the `pickle` module, but then some other serialization is applied (https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/main/crates/polars-plan/src/dsl/python_udf.rs#L53-L76). Line 69 calls pickle, and line 73 does some additional serialization. Also, hope I am looking at the correct part of the source-code.

I am not so familiar with rust, so was unable to track down what this additional serialization is that results in the array I showed above. When I pickle the function, I get the following, so I know some other serialization is happening afterwards:

```
b'\x80\x04\x95\x1c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8c\x08__main__\x94\x8c\x0bmultiplyBy2\x94\x93\x94.'
```

My end objective is to deserialize the array and retrieve the name of the UDF function from the json, in `python`. NB: I do not want to deserialize the entire json back into a LazyDataframe.

Comment: You can call `bytearray(list_of_numbers)` - the numbers are just the "codepoints" e.g. `chr(128) # '\x80'`